# postgresql - Schedule Insert data from dblink to a local table In a

Tags: postgresql, scheduled-tasks, dblink

I am trying to link a remote database to a local database using dblink. What  want to achieve here is:

1. I want to be fetching only data from the latest row(s) every 10 secs from a table in remote  database.
2. I wish to insert the data into a local database into a pre-existing table. In this case, I wish to insert the data I collected from the remote database, plus some others like primary key, and some sequenses which I dont get from the remote database into the table.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You'd need an indexed column in remote table that will increase every time a row will be inserted or updated there (not a timestamp, as many rows can have the same timestamp, a computer clock can sometimes go backwards etc.). If you don't ever update then a serial primary key would suffice (enforce that updates are not allowed with a trigger if you decide to rely on this). Deletes would also not be synchronized, so I'd recommend to enforce that they're not allowed using trigger too.

  You'd need a cron (or scheduler on Windows) job that will connect to your database and perform synchronization, as PostgreSQL has no mechanism for periodic tasks.

  This job would just do:

  ```
  start transaction;
  lock table local_tablename in exclusive mode;
  dblink_connect(…);
  insert into local_tablename (id, data, row_counter)
    select * from dblink(
      'select id, data, row_counter from remote_tablename
         where row_counter>'||(select coalesce(max(row_counter),-1) from local_tablename)
    ) as t(id int, data text, row_counter int);
  commit;
  ```

  It needs to be in transaction and protected with a lock, because it can break if it would run concurrently with another synchronization job (for example if previous job took more than 10 seconds).

  `coalesce` is needed in case `local_tablename` has no rows yet - it would then not insert anything without it. It assumes that always `row_counter>=0`.

Comment: In that case, would I still use dblink, or there's a bettert option for what I want to achieve?  @tometzky?

Comment: I think dblink would be the easiest way. I've updated my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Hello @tometzky your solution worked perfectly, and am getting data from the remote db inserted into my db, but now I have noted that The data get's inserted in an order. Am getting data from three columns from the remote db, but its inserting into the first 3 columns in my local db. I wanted a stuation where I would dictate which data would be inserted where and also i get an opportunity to insert some default values in some columns. I would appreciate if you dont mind explaining further....

Comment: Hey - do your homework. This is basic [SQL insert syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) - `insert into table_name (column_name1, column_name2, column_name3) select …`. I've updated my question that it uses column names in insert.

Comment: Thanks alot. That's all I needed. I had nevr worked with dblink before.. Sorry for many qns...cheers!